# How to get proximity alerts when app is (in background) not active

Tags: android

I have implemented proximity alerts using `LocationManager` and `BroadcastReceiver`.
I have registered `BroadcastReceiver` in `Manifest`file.
These alerts are working fine when app is active and running.
But the problem with proximity alerts is that these are not firing when application is (in background) not active.

Comment: Write a `Service` for it

Comment: Maybe the [Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/)?

Answer (score 0):

Option-1 : Try to use [Creating and Monitoring Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

Option-2 : Use location manager API or FusedLocationAPI inside a service with background threads.

Comment: It means there is no alternative using proximity alerts?